A question from STEMS (by CMI) involving summation and p-adic valuation

Let $$ N = \sum_{i=0}^{2023^9-1} 7i(i+1)(i^2+i+1)$$
Further, let $a = \nu_3(N) $. Find $a^5$. 
NOTE: $\nu_p(x)$ is the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $x$

This is a question from a math olympiad called STEMS conducted by CMI, the Chennai Mathematical Insitute. It is the first question of the 2024 Category A paper, linked here.
My attempts: I was tempted to multiply and divide by $(i-1)^2$, which gives us: $$ N = \sum_{i=0}^{2023^9-1} \frac{7i(i^2 -1)(i^3-1)}{(i-1)^2}$$
I am unsure where to go from here. Another thing I noticed was that it was possible that the sum isn't actually a multiple of 3, so $a$ is simply $0$ (I have yet to check this). Apart from these, I have no ideas.
EDIT: I did consider the partial sum $\sum_{x=0}^n x(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$, but evaluating it at $2023^9 -1$ as well as the sum of $x^4$ has made me feel that it's likely to not be the 'intended' method, which has not yet been provided. A wolfram computation gives the result for the partial sum as $$ \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n^2+2n+2)}{5} $$
Now all I have to do is evaluate it at $n = 2023^9 - 1$, from where I have to just calculate the p-adic valuation of each factor by a formula listed here.

Once you have the partial sum, calculating $v_3(N)$ should be straightforward. EG $v_3(n+1) = v_3(2023^9) = 0 $.

I am trying to find a way without the partial sum, @CalvinLin Moreover, I don't see how finding $v_3(n+1)$ helps us find $v_3(n)$

1/ I don't see a reasonable way without evaluating $N$ in some form. $\quad$ 2/ I never said it did. $ v_3(N) = v_3(n) + v_3(n+1) + v_3(n+2) + v_3(n^2+2n+2)$. Can you show that $v_3(n) = 3$?

I see. Also @CalvinLin I already know how to compute $v_3(N)$ via the partial sum and then using the factors of it, as mentioned in my post. Should I close this question then?

You should make it much clearer that you're looking for an alternative solution, and to also write up the one that you already know. EG You said " I noticed was that it was possible that the sum isn't actually a multiple of 3", which is contradictory to "I already know how to compute $v_3(N)$".  $\quad$ It's fine to ask for alternative solutions.

The original question has $$ N = \sum_{i=0}^{2023^9-1} 7i(i+1)(i^2+i+1)^2$$ not $$ N = \sum_{i=0}^{2023^9-1} 7i(i+1)(i^2+i+1)$$

wait fr!?!?! @NamenotAllowed are you absolutely sure? If so I might as well open a new question?

@Kraken Its not about me being sure, check the pdf uploaded on official website and take action.

First of all the $7$ factor is a waste of our time, so let's dump that.
We have
$$M = \sum_{i = 0}^{2023^9-1} i(i+1)(i^2+i+1) = \sum_{i = 0}^{2023^9-1} (i^2+i)(i^2+i+1) = \sum_{i = 0}^{2023^9-1} i^4+2i^3+2i^2+i = \sum_{i = 0}^{2023^9-1} \frac{(i+1)^5-i^5-1}{5} = \frac{2023^{45}-0^{45}-2023^9}{5} = 2023^9\cdot \frac{2023^{36}-1}{5}$$
where I used telescoping to simplify the summation. We now apply Lifting The Exponent to finish, as now
$$v_3(M) = v_3(2023^{36}-1) = v_3(2023^{2}-1)+v_3(18) = v_3(2022\cdot 2024)+2 = 3$$
so $a = 3$ and $3^5 = 243$.

damn, good approach! I really like how you used a GP formula to skip the tedious calculation and this seems to be the intended approach :)
